# Decode a base64 string (PDF) in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, base64

I am calling a `/download` endpoint via a jQuery AJAX call. The response from the endpoint is a base64 string. When I copy this response and paste it into an online base64 to PDF converter, I get the desired PDF file. However, accessing it through the below code tweaks the string slightly which makes the PDF just a blank document.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/download",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    contentType: "application/json",
    encode: true,
})
    .done(function (data) {
        window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + Base64.encode(data));
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        $('.toast-header strong').html('Download Error');
        $('.toast-body').html('An error occured while downloading the file.');
        let toast = new bootstrap.Toast($('#liveToast'));
        toast.show();
    });
```

I have tried accessing different methods for `data` like `data.toString()` or simply using `data` variable instead of passing it to `Base64.encode()` function with no luck. How can I simply use the plain text that I get from the API response?

- Response from API (Copying this text and pasting it on the online converter gives the right PDF)
  [image]
- Output from `console.log(data)`. Why don't I see it as just plain text similar to the API response?

  [image: enter code here]

Comment: What's the `encode: true,` parameter on the $.ajax options?  It's not mentioned on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Add `dataType:"text"` to your ajax options, then your `data` should match the value you see in the network tab.   Otherwise jquery does an "intelligent guess" - though http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ doesn't mention converting from base64.

Comment: @freedomn-m None of the combinations worked out. It either gives a blank PDF or a URL error : (

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Base64.encode() function, you should use the built-in btoa() function in JavaScript to encode the base64 string.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/download",
  data: JSON.stringify(postData),
  contentType: "application/json",
  encode: true,
})
  .done(function (data) {
    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + btoa(data));
  })
  .fail(function (err) {
    $('.toast-header strong').html('Download Error');
    $('.toast-body').html('An error occurred while downloading the file.');
    let toast = new bootstrap.Toast($('#liveToast'));
    toast.show();
  });
```

Comment: Getting `Uncaught DOMException: String contains an invalid character`. Can't I directly take the data string instead?

Comment: I have added images for better clarity. Hope it helps.

Comment: Try to just add the data without encoding it

Comment: I tried it. The browser says the `URL does not look right`. The URL starts with something like `data:application/pdf;base64,%PDF-1.410obj<</Title(%EF%BF%BD%`. The garbage value is the same as seen in the console image output.

Comment: Maybe try this :
```javascript
const base64Data = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + base64Data);
```

Because btoa can only handle ascii characters

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`. I am relatively new to `JavaScript`.